# Could not find base directory, please set BASE_DIRECTORY to folder containing shared_sources in CMake

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, compilation

I cloned into [this](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_vk_chopper.git) repository and when I ran `CMake` I got the following error :

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:32 (Message):
 could not find base directory, please set BASE_DIRECTORY to folder
 containing shared_sources
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not specified in the documentation (README), this project assumes [shared_sources](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/shared_sources) project to be cloned too.

Possible layouts (according to project's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_vk_chopper/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), `shared_sources` directory contains cloned `shared_sources` project):

1. Common directory with subdirectories:

   - `xxx` - where `gl_vk_chopper` project is cloned,
   - `shared_sources`
2. Under directory with cloned `gl_vk_chopper` you have `shared_sources` directory.
3. Common directory with subdirectories:

   - `xxx`, containing directory `yyy` - where `gl_vk_chopper` project is cloned,
   - `shared_sources`
4. Pass `-DBASE_DIRECTORY=<base-directory>` option to `cmake`, where directory `<base-directory>` contains `shared_sources` directory.

Comment: Thanks in advance.But another problem occurred when I ran make ; the linker said : "cannot find -lshared_sources" and after running cmake manually in the shared_sources directory in order to compile and install the shared object , this error appeared : "cannot be directly invoked".I cannot install that package from my linux software repository .So how can I get rid of that error?

Comment: Hm, it seems that layout (4) implies `shared_sources` library to be already installed (somehow!). If you don't want to do that, resort to one of the other projects layout, without specifying `BASE_DIRECTORY` (and unset this variable with `-UBASE_DIRECTORY`).